# How can I solve this problem as when I install tensorflow package in any version it throw this error for me?

Tags: python, tensorflow

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmGSf.png)
and I use this command to install this package in jupyter notebook
`import sys !{sys.executable} -m pip install tensorflow==1.14`
Anyone can help me to solve this problem ?
I searched a lot about this problem and there's no an accurate solution about it

I try to delete wrapt manually , it throws to me the same error .

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The problem is they shared tensorflow.estimator() for my solution find match versions then you can install them or use a virtual environment.

Comment: I will use VENV

Comment: `Tensorflow 1.x` is deprecated to use and is no longer supported. It is recommended to use `Tensorflow 2.x` and you can use this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) to convert your `TF 1.x` code to `TF 2.x`. Please follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install `Tensorflow 2.x`.